# Direct integral, reference

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, direct-sum

I am looking for a basic reference for the definition of a direct integral and a basic discussion. I know that there is a discussion on this in "Methods of modern mathematical physics, volume 4", but it does not feel very 'self-contained' or simple. Is anyone aware on possibly better references?

Comment: Direct integral of what?  Hilbert spaces? von Neumann algebras?

Comment: I think Hilbert spaces, but perhaps a reference on Von-Neumann algebras would help as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in page 999 of *Kadison, Richard V.; Ringrose, John R.*, Fundamentals of the theory of operator algebras. Volume II: Advanced theory, Pure and Applied Mathematics, 100-2. Orlando etc.: Academic Press (Harcourt Brace Jovanovich, Publishers). XIV, pp. 399-1074. (1986). [ZBL0601.46054](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0601.46054).[image]